# Null response returns a 204

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

My controller returns a 204 when I do a GET request and I don't find any data.

```
[Route("user/v1/[controller]")]
public class UserLoginController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<UserLogin> Get(int userId)
    {
        var userLoginLogic = new UserLoginLogic();

        return await userLoginLogic.GetUserLogin(userId);
    }
}
```

This is only for GET requests, POST, PUT, DELETE return a 200 empty response. This messes with my swagger definition which has a response defined for a 200 response, and I would rather be consistent.

The 204 would be fine if I was serving HTML out of this controller but it is for a REST API.

How do I get it to return a 200?

Comment: Are you running v2.0 or v2.1?

Comment: I am running 2.1

Comment: "HTTP 204 NO CONTENT: The server has successfully fulfilled the request and that there is no additional content to send in the response payload body". It makes perfect sense for a GET that returns no data to return a 204. It makes no sense for a web application (MVC) to return a 204.

Comment: If the protocol is HTTP and the GET does not return content then 204 is in fact the correct success code - anything the 2xx range is success.  You're likely getting a 204 because in fact you are not returning content.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Your last sentence contradicts your comment

Comment: @Cale Not really, web applications are never supposed to return "no content" (how can a user navigate to a page without content?). Unless you mean that I didn't explicitly say "for a GET in a Web API"

Comment: I could update my swagger documentation to also have a definition for a 204 response. It just seems inconsistent with my non GET endpoints that do return a 200 for a empty response by default.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Well I agree if your MVC app is serving HTML content, but my MVC app is a REST API where if a user doesn't have a login, thats ok, and I don't want to retun a 400 class error

Comment: Because you are using the Web API-like side of ASP.NET Core, not the MVC one

Comment: Are you saying you want it to return 200 when it doesn't find a user?  Wouldn't 404 make more sense?

Comment: I could see a 404 making sense, but a 404 is an error, its a 4xx class error. Not finding a user login in our system is not a bad thing, the user might not have a login yet, this is expected. I don't want this to be logged as an error

Comment: Another reason why I think a 404 would be not be consistent is our paginated responses. In endpoint that are paginated, we return a page wrapper model that has pagesize, total records, etc. If the results collection inside the page is empty we return a 200 and that is the default behavior of the controller. I wouldn't want to return a 404 to a caller if a table page is empty.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With the new `ActionResult<T>` in v2.1+ you can also refactor to specifically tell the controller to return Ok 200 using the `Ok()` helper methods

```
[Route("user/v1/[controller]")]
public class UserLoginController : Controller {
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<UserLogin>> Get(int userId) {
        var userLoginLogic = new UserLoginLogic();
        var model = await userLoginLogic.GetUserLogin(userId);
        return Ok(model);
    }
}
```

however this can be misleading if there is in fact no content to return. Consider using an appropriate response status

```
[Route("user/v1/[controller]")]
public class UserLoginController : Controller {
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<UserLogin>> Get(int userId) {
        var userLoginLogic = new UserLoginLogic();
        var model = await userLoginLogic.GetUserLogin(userId);
        if(model == null) return NotFound(); //404
        return Ok(model); //200
    }
}
```

If intent on returning 200 Ok with no content use [`ControllerBase.Ok()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.ok?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ControllerBase_Ok) method

> Creates a OkResult object that produces an empty Status200OK response.

```
[Route("user/v1/[controller]")]
public class UserLoginController : Controller {
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<UserLogin>> Get(int userId) {
        var userLoginLogic = new UserLoginLogic();
        var model = await userLoginLogic.GetUserLogin(userId);
        if(model == null) return Ok(); //200 with no content
        return Ok(model); //200
    }
}
```

Reference [Controller action return types in ASP.NET Core Web API:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-2.1#actionresultt-type)

Comment: That's why I asked about using v2.1, it has the lovely new `ActionResult<T>` too

Comment: Using the return type Task<ActionResult<UserLogin>> returns a 204 when the model is null.

public async Task<IActionResult> Get(int userId)
return Ok(await userLoginLogic.GetUserLogin(userId));

This is also still returning a 204

Comment: `Ok(null)` generates a 204. Instead, if you insist on 200 instead of this answer's suggested 404, you'll need to check for `null` explicitly and use a simple `Ok()` instead: That just means switching out `NotFound()` for `Ok()` in the second example in this answer.

Comment: added comments to the question about why I think a 404 is not appropriate.

Comment: @Nkosi if you add an example where a null model causes a 200 to return then I can mark the question as answered

Comment: @Cale you can just `return Ok();` and it will return 200 with no content.

Answer (score 7):

See:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-3.1#special-case-formatters
- https://www.colabug.com/2020/0224/7036191/
- https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2020/Feb/24/Null-API-Responses-and-HTTP-204-Results-in-ASPNET-Core

---

```
services.AddControllers(opt =>  // or AddMvc()
{
    // remove formatter that turns nulls into 204 - No Content responses
    // this formatter breaks Angular's Http response JSON parsing
    opt.OutputFormatters.RemoveType<HttpNoContentOutputFormatter>();
})
```