# How to return null without 204 response?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nswag

The controller returns 204 when i don't find any data.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class SeasonsController : Controller
{
    private readonly IMediator _mediator;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public SeasonsController(IMediator mediator, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _mediator = mediator;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    [HttpGet, Route("by-betContextId/{betContextId:int}")]
    [SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, typeof(SeasonEntity))]
    public async Task<IActionResult> TryGetByBetContextId(int betContextId)
    {
        SeasonEntity entity = await _mediator.Send(new TryGetSeasonByBetContextId(betContextId));
        //the entity above can be null
        return Ok(entity);
    }
}
```

This is the client which is autogenerated by nswag

```
 /// <param name="cancellationToken">A cancellation token that can be used by other objects or threads to receive notice of cancellation.</param>
    /// <exception cref="SportradarFaultException">A server side error occurred.</exception>
    public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<SeasonEntity> TryGetByBetContextIdAsync(int betContextId, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (betContextId == null)
            throw new System.ArgumentNullException("betContextId");

        var urlBuilder_ = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        urlBuilder_.Append(BaseUrl != null ? BaseUrl.TrimEnd('/') : "").Append("/api/Seasons/by-betContextId/{betContextId}");
        urlBuilder_.Replace("{betContextId}", System.Uri.EscapeDataString(ConvertToString(betContextId, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));

        var client_ = _httpClient;
        try
        {
            using (var request_ = await CreateHttpRequestMessageAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false))
            {
                request_.Method = new System.Net.Http.HttpMethod("GET");
                request_.Headers.Accept.Add(System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue.Parse("application/json"));

                PrepareRequest(client_, request_, urlBuilder_);
                var url_ = urlBuilder_.ToString();
                request_.RequestUri = new System.Uri(url_, System.UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                PrepareRequest(client_, request_, url_);

                var response_ = await client_.SendAsync(request_, System.Net.Http.HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
                try
                {
                    var headers_ = System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary(response_.Headers, h_ => h_.Key, h_ => h_.Value);
                    if (response_.Content != null && response_.Content.Headers != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var item_ in response_.Content.Headers)
                            headers_[item_.Key] = item_.Value;
                    }

                    ProcessResponse(client_, response_);

                    var status_ = (int)response_.StatusCode;
                    if (status_ == 200)
                    {
                        var objectResponse_ = await ReadObjectResponseAsync<SeasonEntity>(response_, headers_).ConfigureAwait(false);
                        if (objectResponse_.Object == null)
                        {
                            throw new SportradarFaultException("Response was null which was not expected.", status_, objectResponse_.Text, headers_, null);
                        }
                        return objectResponse_.Object;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var responseData_ = response_.Content == null ? null : await response_.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false); 
                        throw new SportradarFaultException("The HTTP status code of the response was not expected (" + status_ + ").", status_, responseData_, headers_, null);
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (response_ != null)
                        response_.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
        }
    }
```

When i return Ok() instead of Ok(entity) i take "Response was null which was not expected."

When i make the call from a REST API client i take 204 error.

How do I get it to return a 200 when the data is null?

Comment: What is "nswag" and how do they not know that a successful restful HTTP response has a code in range of [200, 299]? Can you try `return StatusCode(200);` and see if that does it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Null response returns a 204](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51411693/null-response-returns-a-204)

Comment: @RoarS. -- so it looks like if you return `return item == null ? Ok() : Ok(item);` that should do it?

Comment: Yes, I believe so.

Comment: BTW: Your controller can inherit from ControllerBase instead. If you take a look at the source for `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ObjectResult`, you'll see that there are lot of checks for null, hence it will throw exception when `Ok(null)`

Answer (score 1):

This issue is related to how NSwag generates the REST client API.

Option 1: Don't use the auto-generated NSwag client code that obviously *requires* a parsable `SeasonEntity`:

```
var objectResponse_ = await ReadObjectResponseAsync<SeasonEntity>(response_, headers_)
    .ConfigureAwait(false);
if (objectResponse_.Object == null)
{
    throw new SportradarFaultException("Response was null which was not expected.", status_, 
        objectResponse_.Text, headers_, null);
}
```

Option 2: Make sure that you always pass a `SeasonEntity` to the `Ok` method in your controller action to pass the check in the auto-generated client code.

Option 3: Return a `404` response when `entity == null`:

```
[HttpGet, Route("by-betContextId/{betContextId:int}")]
[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, typeof(SeasonEntity))]
public async Task<IActionResult> TryGetByBetContextId(int betContextId)
{
    SeasonEntity entity = await _mediator.Send(new TryGetSeasonByBetContextId(betContextId));

    if (entity == null)
        return NotFound();

    return Ok(entity);
}
```

Option 3 makes more sense than option 2. Why would you want to return a `200` response when no matching item was found?

Comment: _Why would you want to return a 200 response when no matching item was found?_   To indicate that the operation did not have any failures in processing due to the request or server issue, there was just no data.

Comment: If we "Option 1: Don't use the auto-generated NSwag client code", then what do we use to generate a proxy for complex APIs

Answer (score 1):

try to decorate the method of the controller with the attribute

```
[return: CanBeNull]
```

Answer (score 0):

I really struggled to get this working in my latest .Net 8 web API project.  As the client expected to get null in 100s of places so it was essential I got this working.

The first change was in the program.cs file for the Api project.  I added the following:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers(options =>
{
  options.OutputFormatters.RemoveType<HttpNoContentOutputFormatter>();
}).AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
  options.JsonSerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull;
});
```

This excludes items which are null from the json response instead of assigning null in the response.

So instead of returning:

```
{ MyNullValue: null }
```

It would simply return:

```
{ }
```

This also changes the http status from 204 back to 200.

Next, my solution was to create my own NSwag CLI exe using `NSwag.CodeGeneration.CSharp` nuget package.

https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag

I found in the generated SwaggerClient file there was 1 line which was causing this problem.

1. `throw new ApiException("Response was null which was not expected.", status_, objectResponse_.Text, headers_, null);`

After using the nuget package.  Before writing the generated code out to a file.  I ran the following replace commands.

```
var code = generateCode(document);

code = code.Replace("throw new ApiException(\"Response was null which was not expected.\", status_, objectResponse_.Text, headers_, null);", "");
```

The client would then accept a null response without erroring.

Answer (score -1):

I changed the nswag.json configuration from

```
"defaultResponseReferenceTypeNullHandling": "NotNull",
```

to

```
"defaultResponseReferenceTypeNullHandling": "Null",
```

and changed the controller to

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class SeasonsController : Controller
{
    private readonly IMediator _mediator;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public SeasonsController(IMediator mediator, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _mediator = mediator;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    [HttpGet, Route("TryGetByBetContextId")]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(SeasonEntity), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> TryGetByBetContextId(int betContextId)
    {
        SeasonEntity entity = await _mediator.Send(new TryGetSeasonByBetContextId(betContextId));

        if (entity == null)
            return Ok();

        return Ok(entity);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the point of the controller changes if you still return `Ok`...?